# 2 rows having unique field and recent date

Tags: mysql

**Table :**

[image]

I am new to query writing. Now I am stuck on retrieving 2 rows from above table.
Data will be date sorted in descending order for only 2 different topic_id. There won't be a third different topic_id.

So I want to retrieve two rows only that will have different topic_id, one data for each topic_id having most recent date.

**The result would be**

[image]

try [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f37963)

Comment: Your result seems to have 3 rows, the first two exact duplicates. Is that deliberate?

Comment: no thats not delibrate..but anyway @sel answer is what i was looking for..thnks for replying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f37963/9

```
SELECT t1.* FROM temp t1
      JOIN (SELECT question_id, MAX(`date`) as `date` FROM temp GROUP BY topic_id) t2
        ON t1.question_id= t2.question_id AND t1.`date`= t2.`date`;
```

The logic is to find the latest date in each group (subquery) and join it with the table again to retrieve other particulars.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
 $qry="SELECT * FROM table_name GROUP BY TOPIC_ID ORDER BY DATE desc";
```